# How to send emails based on pass/fail conditions in JMeter

Tags: email, controller, jmeter, smtp

[image: Stub here]

I need to send Only one SUCCESS email when ALL the requests mentioned in Type A, B and C pass.
If any of the requests mentioned in ANY of the Type A, B or C fails, there shouldn't be any SUCCESS email, just the failure mail of that request.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Mailer Visualizer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mailer_Visualizer) with `Failure Limit` set to 0. Also set  number in `Success Limit` as you need for getting success mail. You can add fake request that will fail and then you will get success mail only if the number of your requests succeeded.

> Failure Limit
>   Once this number of failed responses is exceeded, a failure email is sent - i.e. set the count to 0 to send an e-mail on the first failure.
>
> Success Limit
>   Once this number of successful responses is exceeded after previously reaching the failure limit, a success email is sent. The mailer will thus only send out messages in a sequence of failed-succeeded-failed-succeeded, etc.

Comment: Thanks @user7294900, trying to implement your solution, will update here once again.

Comment: I have few requests which are failing and don't matter to me, if they do. Now this way I have to guess the exact number to put in to 'failed' field, not working so far!  Thanks though!

Comment: I suggest you mark failed requests that don't matter as successful - add post processor JSR 233 and write `prev.setSuccessful(true)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your `SUCCESS` email [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) into [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)
2. Put it under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with the condition of `${__P(failure,)}`
3. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your main Thread Group
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {props.put('failure', 'true')}
   ```

If any sampler in the main "Thread Group" fails it will set `failure` property to `true` therefore "SUCCESS" mail will be sent out only if there will be no failing requests

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T It didn't work, trying to elaborate question and adding little bit more information here: <br/> I have a CSV file where Type A, B and C are mentioned, based on A, B and C these ‘Export Report’ request have to run, as each set is different in terms of POST parameters. There is a common section of code which is also being executed for each run i.e. A, B etc. (just above 'Export Report') Now for Type = C, request fails but I see that the Export Success mail is sent.